# Déterminer, calculer, évaluer, trouver en mathématiques

Tags: vocabulaire, synonymes, mathématiques

> Déterminer l'inverse de la matrice A.

> Trouver l'inverse de la matrice A.

> Calculer l'inverse de la matrice A.

> Évaluer l'inverse de la matrice A.

1. Quelles sont les nuances, en maths, parmi ces quatre verbes ?
2. Y a-t-il d'autres verbes qui peuvent être utilisés dans ce contexte ?

Comment: Je viens de trouver [cette définition](https://dictionnaire.orthodidacte.com/article/definition-determiner) qui me plait bien : « En maths, on rencontre [... ] le verbe déterminer, en particulier dans les problèmes scolaires. Dans ce contexte, ce verbe signifie « trouver (quelque chose qui n’est pas connu à ce stade) en faisant un calcul ».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Dans ce contexte, à mon sens, « déterminer », « trouver » et « calculer » sont équivalents. J'aurais plutôt tendance à utiliser le terme « calculer. » Par contre « évaluer » aurait plutôt comme sens de déterminer certaines caractéristiques de la matrice A.
2. chercher

Answer (score 1):

Les tois premiers seraient plus précisément applicables si le calcul doit être exact, c'est à dire si le résultat doit être tel que le calcul formel  le produit, alors que le dernier est plus proprement utilisé lorsque les entrées de la matrice sont des approximations à la valeur exacte. Cependant, les trois premiers peuvent aussi être utilisés dans ce dernier cas.